# Restart mysql from JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was wondering if it is possible to restart the database from JDBC. I am dynamically setting mysql system variables, and in order to see if the values I am setting are making any difference I need to restart database after each execution. I could restart it from shell script, but know I am working with java code and so I would like to call database with JDBC rather than calling shell script from java code.

Comment: There are many variables that can be set without restarting, maybe you don't need restart at all. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dynamic-system-variables.html

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is possible for MySQL, you may do this with an Oracle database, see http://www.oracledistilled.com/java/database-startup-and-shutdown-through-jdbc/

Comment: And how does this help for MySQL?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible with MySQL, so I suggested a different database. Thats all the help I can give, and I did because I thought it would be better than nothing.

Comment: You you are suggesting the OP should switch from a free database to a really expensive one, just because there isn't a way to do it in MySQL? Hardly a good answer.

Comment: it's a bit late for me to switch to Oracle now)but thank you for your replies!

Comment: hey @Doberman, he (@user3344382) want the solution in mysql. Did you mention the link in oracle. lot of difference for oracle and mysql. you must see the tags.

Comment: I saw the tags. I answered the question (not possible). And I mentioned an alternative (Oracle). What is your problem?

Comment: In my experience, switching backend databases is not a oft-occurring practice.